# Add 1 to a digits linked list

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given a linked list such that each node is a digit from a number.

For example: If number is 1234, the corresponding linked list is:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> [\]
```

The problem is to add 1 to this number. So the output will be:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 5 -> [\]
```

We can do it recursively in O(n) time with O(n) space. Is it possible to optimize the solution to O(logn) time complexity?

**Update:**
n is total number of digits.

Comment: if you change the direction of the linked list (`[\] <- 1 <- 2 <- 3 <- 5`) it will be O(1) (or O(2))

Comment: @asciimoo: Actually it will be O(n) worst-case and O(1) average case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, provided you have no additional data structure.

Since the last node in the list will always change, and it takes O(n) time for any algorithm to reach there (you must chase the whole list if you have no additional data structure), that gives O(n) as your lower bound.

Comment: Thanks Charles, I also thought the same. Just curious what data structure can I go for if I have millions of digits and I just want to add one to it? Can any DS reduce the complexity to O(logn)?

Comment: @KevindraSingh - Sure: you can have a list of pointers to the nodes of this list in reverse order. This allows you to zoom to the last element, and visit the cells in reverse order as you need to to perform carries. This allows you an O(1) average case, though still O(n) worst case.

Answer (score 0):

What is `n`? If `n` is the number of digits in the number, I don't think a `O(log(n))` solution is possible.

If n is the number itself, then the number of digits is already `O(log(n))`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to traverse through each number before you can perform the operation, there is no other way but as you know the total number of elements therefore you can write all the moving operations like head->next->next->next... in a same line instead of a for loop. This will quicken up the process as the overload time complexity of a running for loop will be avoided.